# Telerik RadScheduler - select multiple resources

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radscheduler

I'm using Telerik scheduler to display a Timeline view of meetings.  The resources derive from the Person class, and they are Advocate, and Legislator.

On the Y axis, I am listing Advocates, and on the X axis, I am listing blocks of time in one hour increments.

When I double click an appointment, the Edit Appointment modal dialog pops up and lists Advocates and Legislators.

Since meetings will have multiple advocates and possibly multiple legislators in attendance, I would like to have a checkbox list inside the resource dropdowns on the edit screen.  Is there any way to accomplish this?

I believe this will allow me to solve  one problem in that, if Peter Pan and Homer Simpson both are to attend the same meeting, clicking the meeting in the row for either of those two advocates will display 'Peter Pan' in both instances (or sometimes '-', not yet sure where that comes from) rather than 'Homer Simpson' where I open up the meeting from his row.

If it is not possible to introduce checkboxes to the resources list, can you suggest an alternate way around the ultimate issue in the above paragraph?  Thanks in advance.

[image: I would like to add checkboxes to the resource lists on the Edit Appointment dialog]

Comment: Perhaps a listbox would be more appropriate? (http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/listbox.aspx#multiple/single-selections)

Comment: Sure, but is it possible to manipulate the edit appointment dialog to use a listbox rather than the default dropdown?  I haven't seen an example of this, and I haven't been able to figure out if it's possible, let alone how to get there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Telerik supports the adding of a listbox to support what you are trying to do. On the Scheduler itself add the code below that mimics your field names that your advocates are pulling from in your DB:

```
<ResourceTypes>
                <telerik:ResourceType DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" ForeignKeyField="Adv_AdvocateID" 
                    KeyField="Adv_AdvocateID" Name="Advocate" TextField="Adv_FullName" AllowMultipleValues="true" />               
            </ResourceTypes>
```

The next step is to populate the resources using a custom provider. See [this program here for a great project in which you can see resource population in action.](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/customize-the-advanced-form-with-the-advanced-template-user-controls.aspx) Using the SchedulerDBProvider class you can then adjust their example to more represent your fields and populate the appointments accordingly with your desired ResourceTypes.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of getting that particular drop down to have multiple selections via checkboxes you would most likely have to define your own custom advanced template. This route allows you to take a UserControl and use that as the edit view for your appointments. There's a demo that displays all of this (including source code) [right here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/advancedformtemplate/defaultcs.aspx).

However, having that RadComboBox there might not even be the ideal approach to take. What about just a simple list of checkboxes? [This demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/multipleresourcevalues/defaultcs.aspx) shows off how a very simple declaration for the RadScheduler can achieve this functionality. Additionally, there is some code-behind (both in C# and VB.NET) that shows off how you can customize the text on each appointment, which might be helpful in the case that you're referring to.